# Remove values from rows in R

Tags: r

I have one dataframe having two below columns("Name" & "Code").I would like to remove the rows which has numeric values in R. Please help me in this.

```
Name   Code
Sam    SDFCVH
Julia  KALMN
Hari   123456
Merry  432168
Jazz   AWEQRY
Martin 410000
```

Answer (score 1):

We can use `grep` to create a logical index by matching zero or more digits (`[0-9]+`) from start (`^`) to end (`$`), negate (`!`) and `subset` the rows

```
subset(df, !grepl("^[0-9]+$", Code))
```

Or convert the 'Code' to `numeric` and all the non-numeric elements will become `NA`, check for those elements with `is.na` and `subset`

```
subset(df, is.na(as.numeric(Code)))
```